# How to strip HTML tags when using XPath in Python?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am running this code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'smm'
    allowed_domains = []
    #f = open("E:\Usuarios\Daniel\GitHub\SocialMedia-Web-Scraper\socialmedia\Links.txt")
    #start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    #f.close()
    start_urls =['http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/pinterest-interests-what-marketers-need-to-know/']
    rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=('statcounter.com/','wikipedia','play.google','books.google.com','github.com','amazon','bit.ly','wikimedia','mediawiki','creativecommons.org',
                                         'extensions.joomla.org','contact','about','careers','jobs','itunes.apple','apple','microsoft','clevnet.bibliocommons.com')), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
             )
    def parse_items(self, response):
        items = []
        #Define keywords present in metadata to scrap the webpage
        keywords = ['social media','social business','social networking','social marketing','online marketing','social selling',
            'social customer experience management','social cxm','social cem','social crm','google analytics','seo','sem',
            'digital marketing','social media manager','community manager']
        #Extract webpage keywords 
        metakeywords = response.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract()
        #Compare keywords and extract if one of the defined keyboards is present in the metadata
        if any(key in metakey for key in keywords for metakey in metakeywords):
            for link in response.xpath("//a"):
                item = SocialMediaItem()
                item['SourceTitle'] = link.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
                item['SourceDomain'] = urlparse((link.xpath('/html/head/link[@rel="canonical"]').extract()  or [''])[0]).hostname
                item['description'] = link.xpath('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
                item['webKW'] = metakeywords
                item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract()
                item['TargetDomain'] = urlparse((link.xpath('@href').extract() or [''])[0]).hostname
                item['TargetTitle'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
                outbound = str(link.xpath('@href').extract())
                if 'http' in outbound:
                    items.append(item)
        return items
```

I have problems getting the `SourceTitle` item without HTML tags. I have tried to do it as in the `TargetTitle` item (this works), that is `urlparse((link.xpath('/html/head/link[@rel="canonical"]').extract()  or [''])[0]).hostname`, but it returns an empty item. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Dani

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I just changed `/html/head/link[@rel="canonical"]` for `//link[@rel='canonical']/@href`